# How to add data using ember-power-select-with-create?

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to figure out how to properly use `ember-power-select-with-create` on [gh readme](https://github.com/cibernox/ember-power-select-with-create/find/master), but I am stuck on the example.

Here is an example given:

```
{{#power-select-with-create
    options=countries
    selected=selectedCountry
    onchange=(action (mut selectedCountry))
    oncreate=(action "createCountry") as |country term|
}}
  {{country.name}}
{{/power-select-with-create}}
```

I am not able to figure out how I should define `createCountry` controller action. Can someone help me to understand how I should define `createCountry`? Pseudocode works. Assume the template above is on `application.hbs` template and countries array below is in `application.js` controller

```
  countries: [
    { name: 'United States',  flagUrl: '/flags/us.svg' },
    { name: 'Spain',          flagUrl: '/flags/es.svg' },
    { name: 'Portugal',       flagUrl: '/flags/pt.svg' },
    { name: 'Russia',         flagUrl: '/flags/ru.svg' },
    { name: 'Latvia',         flagUrl: '/flags/lv.svg' },
    { name: 'Brazil',         flagUrl: '/flags/br.svg' },
    { name: 'United Kingdom', flagUrl: '/flags/gb.svg' },
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a country object and push it to `countries` array probably as follows;

```
createCountry(countryName){
    let newCountry = {name: countryName, flagUrl: 'flags/unknown.svg'}; 
    this.get('countries').pushObject(newCountry);
}
```

You should consider putting an unknown flag for newly added countries.